# javascript: set title of option in select tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I am working on a project where I have a select tag with its options being generated in a javascript function. I am currently populating the "title" attribute of each option with a detailed description.
Inside the javascript function I am currently doing something like this:

```
var country = new Option("countryUSA", "United States of America");
$("#mySelect").get(0).options[1]=country;
```

This works fine, the option shows up. However, I also need to set the "title" attribute of that html option element. I have tried something like this:

```
country.title="Full description of USA";
```

but it does not work.
I know I can do something like this:

```
 $("#mySelect").get(0).options[1].title="My title";
```

but I was trying to set the title before adding the option to the select tag. Isn't the "Option" object suppose to allow me to set the "title" property? The javascript function is not even executed. Is there no way I can set the "title" attribute for an "option" html element in javascript?

Comment: I don't think the `Option` object is technically an HTML node until it is added to the select.  So, if it doesn't support the `title` property, that won't get translated to a `title` attribute.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"The javascript function is not even executed?"_ What JS function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using jQuery. There is a much simpler way to do what you want. Just use [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery2) rather than regressing back to vanilla DOM:

```
$('<option>',
{
    value: 'countryUSA',
    title: 'Full description of USA',
    text: 'United States of America'
}).appendTo("#mySelect");
```

That said, do you expect setting the `title` to make a browser-native tooltip to appear while the hovering over the `<option>`? At least in Chrome, no such tooltip will appear.

Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/GMTLn/1/

---

***Edit*** Chrome and Safari do not show a tooltip on `<option>`s with a `title` attribute because WebKit doesn't. See [this bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10843).

Comment: @patrick thanks for the edit, but the fiddle wasn't intended to have any JS - just demonstrate that the `title` attribute on `<option>`s doesn't show a tooltip :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I completely missed the point. Thought you just pasted the wrong link.

Comment: thank you Matt. The title shows as a tooltip in latest version of Firefox and IE. This is the simplest way I found to show a specific tooltip for each option. I have not tested it in Chrome. Do you guys have any other suggestion? Here was my original post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949712/struts2-how-to-show-a-tooltip-for-each-dropdown-option-in-a-select-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can set the title attribute

```
   $('#mySelect').append(
   $("<option/>", { text: value }).attr("title",value));
```

Here is a working sample http://jsbin.com/ozudoTod/1/

Or this way :

```
     value = cleanNulls( value );
     var option = $( '<option/>', {
     title: value,
     text: value
     });
     $('#mySelect').append( option );
```